# Do we say "to hold the stick of the ice cream"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Look at the picture

[image]

Do we say "**to hold the stick of the ice cream**"?

Comment: You need only google **icecream sticks**. https://www.amazon.com/Perfect-Stix-Wooden-Craft-Sticks/dp/B01IRR8GZS

Comment: For example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paddle_Pop (a specific brand of ice cream sold in Australia / NZ) says: "It is held for eating by a wooden stick which protrudes at the base and is known as a Paddle Pop stick (used commonly for arts and crafts and known also as a popsicle stick[1][2] or craft stick[3])."

Comment: the simple answer is a "stick".  I ***think*** literally in the industry it is called a "paddle", but don't quote me on that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In British English, it would be called a *lolly stick* - the equivalent of the American *popsicle stick*. This is because, even though the confection might be made of ice-cream, it is being served in the form of a lolly / popsicle. Ice-cream is traditionally served in a *cone*. Further, ice-cream sold in this form is usually a different consistency so as not to melt quickly and fall off the stick. As such it is regarded as a different product to an ice-cream.

A British English speaker would probably say:

- hold the stick
- hold the lolly stick
- hold your ice-cream by the stick

I can't say for certain what an American would say about the same kind of confection, but I'm fairly certain that the stick itself, in isolation, doesn't have two names. It is the same kind of stick you find in a 'popsicle' so it would be a *popsicle-stick*.

[This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lolly%20stick%2C%20popsicle%20stick%2C%20ice-cream%20stick%2C%20icecream%20stick&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clolly%20stick%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpopsicle%20stick%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cice%20-%20cream%20stick%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cicecream%20stick%3B%2Cc0) compares usage of lolly stick, popsicle stick, and two variations of ice-cream stick (with and without hyphen). All appear to be used, but "popsicle stick" is used most frequently.

Comment: "hold your ice-cream by the stick" sounds plenty reasonable to my American ears.

Comment: The name for frozen confection varies enormously from region to region. However, "[local-name-for-frozen-confection] stick" would seem to be the most idiomatic for the handle sticking out.

Comment: @CJDennis That sounds reasonable to me too, but once the ice-cream is eaten and all you are left with is the stick, what would you call it then? What would you call it if you saw the stick lying around as litter and didn't know what it had once held? I think there must be a default name for it, and I would think lollies/popsicles are what they are most closely associated with.

Comment: I live in Australia, so the most common names for me are "ice cream stick" (with milk) and "icypole stick" (without milk). In Australia a lolly is not frozen. A Chupa Chup is a lolly(pop) with a stick. Lollies are usually room temperature sweets other than chocolate, fudge, etc. E.g. jubes (soft), humbugs (hard), etc. Once the ice cream is finished, you are left with an ice cream stick or an icypole stick. Replace "ice cream" or "icypole" with your local name for the frozen confection on a stick.

Comment: @CJDennis I asked my friend who lives in Sydney about this, and they said (without me mentioning anything in particular) it's a Paddle Pop stick. It may be that it also varies from one city and generation to another.

Comment: @userr2684291 Paddle Pops are a specific type of ice cream. We might call them [Paddle Pop](https://cdn0.woolworths.media/content/wowproductimages/large/700377.jpg) sticks in Victoria as well. We would understand ice cream stick, [Icy Pole](https://cdn0.woolworths.media/content/wowproductimages/large/007280.jpg) stick, and popsicle stick, but not lolly stick.

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is "**popsicle stick"**.

***Simply Google that phrase*** for a vast number of results:

[image]